# css issue in ios devices

Tags: html, css

Kindly check this website in a desktop computer:

http://www.imageworkz.asia/cranium

The header and footer here looks fine in a desktop computer but if you view this in an iPad or any mobile device. The header and footer looks as if it is not complete.

If you check that out in firebug, the width of those are all set to 100% so I see no reason for it to not accomodate the whole 100%.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably not such a good idea to insult potential customers by telling them that their browser is ancient, even if that is the truth.

Comment: guess i'll have to change that. It is the default sentence of the HTML5 Boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 Boilerplate is responsive. If you shrink your browser size, it will emulate the same response as the iPad (or other small devices) with a new resolution. The `header` and `footer` takes on new widths. You may want to check the css media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 media queries to target ipad styling: Something like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```